# SQL server error when browsing from IIS in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

**Server Error in '/' Application.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Name Pipes Provider, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)**

I have created an asp.net application in IIS, in a windows server 2008 R2. When I try to browse the application from the IIS it gives me the above mentioned error. I deployed the app from Visual Studio using the FileSystem. The server and instance name are correct in the connectionString. The database exists in Microsoft SQL Server Management, I just want to connect and use it. Things I tried to fix this error:

- Turning off the Windows Firewall and creating an Inbound Rule for the SQL TCP port 1433 and 90 (port 90 because I configured my app to use that port).
- Enabling the TCP/IP protocol under SQL Server Network Configuration in (SQL Server Configuration Manager).
- Starting the SQL Server and SQL Server Agent.

Here is my connection string:

`<add name="sqlConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PRH-TEMP\SPARTANSOFT; Initial Catalog=Library; Integrated Security=True; User ID=sa; Password=******; Connect Timeout=15; Encrypt=False; TrustServerCertificate=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

I used Entity Framework Code First. My SQL Server allows remote connections. Server authentication: SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.

Comment: where is the connection string?

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: <add name="sqlConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PRH-TEMP\SPARTANSOFT; Initial Catalog=Library; Integrated Security=True; User ID=sa; Password=******; Connect Timeout=15; Encrypt=False; TrustServerCertificate=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: So you can connect from SSMS on the IIS box?, and the SQL Server is a different server - is that right?

Comment: Firstly, `integrated security` and `user id / password` are mutually exclusive. Decide which security method you are going to use (SQL or Windows) and change your connection string. That won't fix your error but it reduces confusion

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I removed the integrated security, thanks. No the SQL Server is installed in server (Windows Server) and both are 2008 R2.

Comment: Please don't use the SA account :( create a specific account with relevant permissions to the database

Comment: Does in server mean the same server or a different server? If it's the same server and you can connect with SSMS then you probably don't have named pipes enabled. You could try this to see if that is the case: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/sql-force-the-protocol-tcp-named-pipes-etc-in-your-connection-string

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Same server

Comment: @Matt I created that SA account with the relevant permission to my Library database.

Comment: i.e. change `Data Source=PRH-TEMP\SPARTANSOFT;` to `Data Source=PRH-TEMP\SPARTANSOFT;Network Library=DBMSSOCN` to force TCP/IP instead of named pipes

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It still gives the same error with the difference is this line:  (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: OK. roll back the connection string change and use this guide to ensure that TCP/IP is enabled for the client: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181035(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Still not working. I appreciate your replies but I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: I know it seems a bit scattershot but this is what I would do to troubeshoot. Another thing you can do is connect in SSMS and run this query to check what protocol you are connecting under `SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections`. It should tell you if you are connecting successfully under named pipes or tcp/ip. Then you know which protocol is working

Comment: Basically it seems your client is connecting on named pipes. We don't know if thats because it tried to connect on tcp/ip and failed, or whether the client is set up to only connect on named pipes... this is all assuming you can connect in SSMS - you can connect right?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I ran the query you said. The column 'protocol_type' is TSQL.   'client_tcp_port' and 'local_tcp_port' columns both have a value of NULL.

Comment: What is under `net_transport`? Shared memory? When connecting in SSMS go to the advanced tab and under network protocol, test a connection as TCP/IP and Named pipes - do these work? This has some explanation about how a protocol is selected: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187662(v=sql.105).aspx From your error message it's trying to use named pipes and failing. If you can get it to use shared memory you might have more luck